# write protect modular plug

Tags: gpio, sd-card

In the older version of Raspberry pi, the mollex connector for the SD card has a switch at the base of  the connector. If you read about it, this is called a write protect switch, that attempts to disable IO write if the SD card is becoming dislodged. That functionality was never built into the original Raspberry Pi model.  Is it hooked up in the new version of the Raspberry PI?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the write protect line has been left unconnected on all the Pi models.

The available hardware [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings).